# PowerBI: Yes/No if date falls within moving month-based period (REVISED)

Tags: powerbi

**Goal:** I am trying to filter a line chart that has trends both 3 months back and 6 months out (a total of a 10 month block).

**Attempted Method:** I tried to create a binary DAX-based yes/no filter as a column in a selected query based on the `End` date column.

I have the code for my attempt at creating this formula shown below.

My code:

```
DateBridge = 
VAR TodayMonthYr = VALUE(FORMAT(today(),"YYYYMM") 
VAR EndMonthYr = VALUE(FORMAT([End],"YYYYMM")

RETURN 
IF(
   AND(
       EndMonthYr > TodayMonthYr - 3 , 
       EndMonthYr < TodayMonthYr + 6
   ),
   "Yes" , "No"
)
```

Comment: Are you planning to use `analytical/windowing functions`?  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language/Window_functions

Comment: Please make sure to format all code as markdown when in the body of questions. This makes it easier for people to read and understand what you are asking in turn learning to a higher chance of getting your question answered.

Comment: @javadba - Looking at your link, I think DAX is already a bit overwhelming enough. My brain is still too Excel centric. This feels a bit further than I'm prepared to comprehend, atm!

Comment: @Ethan - Roger!